# Hash rate of three million mining Monero?

Tags: hashrate, algorithm, random-x, fpga-mining, fpga-development

Is this article truthful when it quotes a hash rate of three million when mining Monero? If so, what is the way to learn and apply the RandomX algorithm in FPGA hardware? What knowledge is required?

BitHull-Overtakes-ASIC-Market-with-New-FPGA-Miners

Comment: "Is this article truthful..." No.

Answer (score 1):

"Is this article truthful when it quotes a hash rate of three million when mining Monero?"

Answer: No. If the hashrate was 3 million, then everyone who was mining Bitcoin must've moved for no reason.

"If so, what is the way to learn and apply the RandomX algorithm in FPGA hardware? What knowledge is required?"

Answer: It is not possible to apply the RandomX Algorithm to FGPA hardware (Currently).